# Project Euler #23 - Unable to figure out error in code

Tags: python

Link : http://projecteuler.net/problem=23

> This is a warning do not look further if you do not want to know the answer.

I have been stuck for quite some time.I know there are solutions online. But I am just not able to figure out the problem in my code. I have attached the code for the code and the factors module that I have created. Any help appreciated.

Actual answer = 4179871.    My answer = 4190404

```
from math import *
from time import *
from prime import *
from factors import *
```

abundant = list(n for n in xrange(12,28124) if n < sum_of_factors(n))

sums = {}

for i in abundant:
    for j in abundant:
        if (i+j) > 28123:
            break
        else:
            sums[i+j] = 1

non_abun = [i for i in range(1,28124)]
print sum(non_abun) - sum(sums)

Code for factors -

```
from time import *
from math import *
```

def factors(num):
    factors_array = [1,]

```
n = num
for k in range(2,int(ceil(sqrt(num)))):
    if(n%k == 0):
        if(k not in factors_array):
            factors_array.append(k)
            factors_array.append(n/k)

return factors_array
```

def sum_of_factors(num):
    return sum(factors(num))

Comment: `n/2` can be a proper divisor of `n`, but your code stops at `ceil(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: I have the k and n/k while appending the factors .. shouldn't that option cover the n/2 options when I hit 2?

Comment: Ah, missed that line. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`factors(4)` should give `[1,2]`, but yield `[1]`. Fix your `factors` function.

Comment: yup. All square numbers are going to have a big problem. Nice call. `ceil(sqrt(num))` needs to be `floor(sqrt(num)) + 1` or something like it

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. That was the problem. Rest of the code runs fine